# SwipeyTabs - how to create Swipey Tabs using ActionBarSherlock Library?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I have created swipey tabs using ViewPagerExtensions but this time i am using only one library  ActionBarSherlock in my App and i dont know how to create swipey tabs like google play store. If you can help me to get it done, i'd be very thankful to you.

This is the onCreate method of my activity class

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setTheme(SampleList.THEME); //Used for theme switching in samples
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_tabs);
        mTabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        mTabHost.setup();

        mTabManager = new TabManager(this, mTabHost, R.id.realtabcontent);

        mTabManager.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("simple").setIndicator("Groups"),FragmentStackSupport.CountingFragment.class, null);
        mTabManager.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("contacts").setIndicator("Contacts"),LoaderCursorSupport.CursorLoaderListFragment.class, null);
        mTabManager.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("custom").setIndicator("Logs"),LoaderCustomSupport.AppListFragment.class, null);
        mTabManager.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("throttle").setIndicator("Gallery"),LoaderThrottleSupport.ThrottledLoaderListFragment.class, null);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mTabHost.setCurrentTabByTag(savedInstanceState.getString("tab"));
        }
    }
```

[image: In first image Top New Paid is the current screen title and other two are showing previous or next screen tile. How can i show previous and next screen title at corner with some fading effect like it.]

In first image Top New Paid is the current screen title and other two are showing previous or next screen tile. How can i show previous and next screen title at corner with some fading effect like it.

Comment: I have created scrollable tabs by using HorizontalScrollView around TabWidget in fragment_tabs.xml.

Comment: <HorizontalScrollView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:scrollbars="none">
          <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"/>  
       
        </HorizontalScrollView>

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use ActionBar Tabs, a TabsAdapter and a ViewPager (scrolly bit). Here's a full tutorial I made: http://davidjkelley.net/?p=34 (just use the ABS imports, not standard compatibility library ones).

Here's some of the relevant code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener;
public class Polling extends FragmentActivity {
private ViewPager mViewPager;
private TabsAdapter mTabsAdapter;
private final static String TAG = "21st Polling:";

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

mViewPager = new ViewPager(this);
mViewPager.setId(R.id.pager);
setContentView(mViewPager);
final ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
bar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
bar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);

mTabsAdapter = new TabsAdapter(this, mViewPager);
mTabsAdapter.addTab(bar.newTab().setText(R.string.login),
LoginFragment.class, null);
mTabsAdapter.addTab(bar.newTab().setText(R.string.economics),
EconFragment.class, null);
mTabsAdapter.addTab(bar.newTab().setText(R.string.elections),
ElectionsFragment.class, null);
mTabsAdapter.addTab(bar.newTab().setText(R.string.politics),
PoliticsFragment.class, null);
mTabsAdapter.addTab(bar.newTab().setText(R.string.science),
ScienceFragment.class, null);
mTabsAdapter.addTab(bar.newTab().setText(R.string.finance),
FinanceFragment.class, null);
mTabsAdapter.addTab(bar.newTab().setText(R.string.religion),
ReligionFragment.class, null);
mTabsAdapter.addTab(bar.newTab().setText(R.string.military),
MilitaryFragment.class, null);
mTabsAdapter.addTab(bar.newTab().setText(R.string.international),
InternationalFragment.class, null);
}

public static class TabsAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter
    implements ActionBar.TabListener, ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {
        private final Context mContext;
        private final ActionBar mActionBar;
        private final ViewPager mViewPager;
        private final ArrayList<TabInfo> mTabs = new ArrayList<TabInfo>();

        static final class TabInfo {
            private final Class<?> clss;
            private final Bundle args;

            TabInfo(Class<?> _class, Bundle _args) {
                clss = _class;
                args = _args;
            }
        }

        public TabsAdapter(FragmentActivity activity, ViewPager pager) {
            super(activity.getSupportFragmentManager());
            mContext = activity;
            mActionBar = activity.getActionBar();
            mViewPager = pager;
            mViewPager.setAdapter(this);
            mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
        }

        public void addTab(ActionBar.Tab tab, Class<?> clss, Bundle args) {
            TabInfo info = new TabInfo(clss, args);
            tab.setTag(info);
            tab.setTabListener(this);
            mTabs.add(info);
            mActionBar.addTab(tab);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }


        public int getCount() {
            return mTabs.size();
        }

        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            TabInfo info = mTabs.get(position);
            return Fragment.instantiate(mContext, info.clss.getName(), info.args);
        }


        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
        }


        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            mActionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }


        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
        }


        public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            Log.v(TAG, "clicked");
            Object tag = tab.getTag();
            for (int i=0; i<mTabs.size(); i++) {
                if (mTabs.get(i) == tag) {
                    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(i);
                }
            }
        }

        public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {}

        public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {}

        public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, android.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {}

        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, android.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {    
            Object tag = tab.getTag();
            for (int i=0; i<mTabs.size(); i++) {
                if (mTabs.get(i) == tag) {
                    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(i);
                }
            }
        }

        public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, android.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {}
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The *swipey tabs* you are referring to is actually just a ViewPager with corresponding title tabs for each page. This is not included in the Android SDK by default, but you can use Jake Wharton's `ViewPagerIndicator` to add the titles for each tab in your ViewPager. I believe that `ActionBarSherlock` (which is also created by Jake Wharton) provides the same exact functionality as well.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue but I wasn't implementing any ActionBar at all. I came across this blog which led me to an implementation called "SwipeyTabs" that is simply used with a ViewPager.

http://blog.peterkuterna.net/2011/09/viewpager-meets-swipey-tabs.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ActionBarSherlock, you'd better use action bar tabs, not `TabHost`. Also I believe there are samples in ABS that show how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use ViewPager, and ditch the TabHost.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html

Comment: @OP (not chubbard), this is the base code that I used in my own response to your question. They're very similar. Just remember to use ABS imports rather than the compatibility library!