# Android: How to Fill SwipeyTabs?

Tags: android

I'm using `SwipeyTabs` in my application. I'm not sure how to fill tabs content. It does not even have any own xml.

I'm using tabs like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_swipey_tabs);
    initViewPager(4, 0xFFFFFFFF, 0xFF000000);
    mSwipeyTabs = (SwipeyTabsView) findViewById(R.id.swipey_tabs);
    mSwipeyTabsAdapter = new SwipeyTabsAdapter(this);
    mSwipeyTabs.setAdapter(mSwipeyTabsAdapter);
    mSwipeyTabs.setViewPager(mPager);
}

private void initViewPager(int pageCount, int backgroundColor, int textColor) {
    mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mPagerAdapter = new ExamplePagerAdapter(this, pageCount, backgroundColor, textColor);
    mPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
    mPager.setCurrentItem(1);
    mPager.setPageMargin(1);
}
```

And here is `activity_swipey_tabs.xml` layout:

```
<android.ex.com.viewpager.extension.SwipeyTabsView
    android:id="@+id/swipey_tabs"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#3B3B3B" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/colorline"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="2dip"
    android:layout_below="@+id/swipey_tabs"
    android:background="#FF91A438" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/blackline"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dip"
    android:layout_below="@+id/colorline"
    android:background="#FF000000" />

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/blackline" />
```

Are there any examples or tutorials?

Any support would great.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10912602/swipeytabs-how-to-create-swipey-tabs-using-actionbarsherlock-library check this

Comment: You sure is this what's I'm looking for? If yes, for example how can I set any TextView or sthelse's listener? Btw thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tabs of `SwipeyTabs` are like virtual layout, I mean they don't have own defined layout. You should define every component in dynamically.

Let me explain with details. In example, you need a ListView (custom). You created layout like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:background="#ffffff" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/i1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView1"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Now you need an `ArrayAdapter` too for adapting this custom `ListView`, I'm not including `ArrayAdapter`.

So in your `PagerAdapter` class, define a `ListView` and use this layout. In example:

```
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(View container, int position) {
    ListView v = new ListView( mContext );
    //test_list_layout which is above
    TestAdapter adapter = new TestAdapter(mContext, R.layout.test_list_layout, objs);

    v.setAdapter( adapter );
    ((ViewPager)container ).addView( v, 0 );
    v.setSelection( scrollPosition[ position ] );
    v.setOnScrollListener( new OnScrollListener() {             
         public void onScrollStateChanged( AbsListView view, int scrollState ){}
         public void onScroll( AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount ) {
        scrollPosition[ pos ] = firstVisibleItem;
         }
    });
    return v;
}
```

Now it's work well. If you need more tabs, use `position` parameter as a seperator like `if(position == 0)`. In this you're gonna need this line:

```
((ViewPager) container).removeView((View) container);
```

That's all. I hope, it's clear.