# How to switch between different activities like tabs in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-widget

[image]

I need to develop an application which contain these tabs shown in the image. Each tab contain a form which will be filled by the user.User can switch to any tab.

User click Activity1, Activity 1 gets displayed and user enters some data; then user press Activity 2, activity 2 gets displayed, user press Activity1 again, Activity 1 gets displayed with the data entered by the user(not the blank activity).

At the end when user click "Save" I need to get all the data from these activities and save it somewhere.

I have worked a lot in java but new to android, I am stuck in developing the UI for this scenario. However I have done this many times in iOS.

Anybody please share your experience of developing such UI.

Thanks,

Comment: I think you will be needing fragments on it.

Comment: please try to Activity1 data set in Onresume method so i think when u back activity2 to activity1 so run OnresumeMethod not Oncreate method.

Comment: And also take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10912602/swipeytabs-how-to-create-swipey-tabs-using-actionbarsherlock-library You might be of a need of `ViewPager` or `SwipeView`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fragments will be more suitable for this scenario, the benefit are

1. They are light weight and faster
2. Managed automatically by the FragmentManager.
3. Data Sharing between Fragments is smoother and simpler than it is for Activities
4. They don't complicate the Architecture of the Application

You can have as many Fragments as you want in you Activity. Following two links can be useful for you.

[A similar Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5710573/need-a-fragments-example)

[A Good Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidFragments/article.html)

[Another good tutorial](http://marakana.com/s/post/1250/android_fragments_tutorial)

If even after that you decide to use Activities, You need to think

Comment: I have implemented it using fragments but how can I access data from all the fragments? Thanks

Comment: Put the variables in  Activity, generate getter/ setter and than from Fragments call `((YourActivity) getActivity()).<your method name i.e. getter / setter>`.... Consider designing separate classes for set of variable which are related to each other. So that data sharing is further enhanced...