# how to hide tabs when using actionbarsherlock?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

When using actionbarsherlock, when there are a lot of tabs how to hide other tabs and only show three or four tabs and when I slide the tabs I can see the tabs hidden?

thanks~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite your short description of the problem, I guess the following link should give you the answer:
[SwipeyTabs - how to create Swipey Tabs using ActionBarSherlock Library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10912602/swipeytabs-how-to-create-swipey-tabs-using-actionbarsherlock-library)

If that does not help, please try to rephrase your question after reading this:
http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html

Comment: I tried different tabs and it seems that when the tabs' text are long enough or there are a lot of tabs only three tabs will be shown.

Comment: I'm still not quite sure what you're trying to achieve. Can you please state your problem more precisely?
If I understood you right, you want to: (1) show only 3 tabs (2) but you've got more than 3 tabs (3) the other tabs shall be accessible by scrolling the actionbar
Is that right so far?

Comment: Yes, just like the tabs on the chome explore. If you open a lot of tabs you will not be able to see the text of every tab. In this case, the other tabs will be hidden to the right side and when you scroll to right, the other tabs will show out.

Comment: I must be using some other Chrome, because I'm waiting for 2 years now for google to implement scrolling tabs :(
Anyways, if I recall it right, all tabs in the actionbar (and sherlock) always have the same size (width and height). Every tab's dimensions depend on the biggest tab, like the one with the longest string (name). So, this is not really manipulable.
What exactly didn't you like about the approach from the link I posted in the answer (Swipey Tabs).

Comment: I am sorry that I did not explain this clearly. The chrome is just example and of course that the tabs on the chrome cannot slide now. Now, I find than if you add a lot of tabs, the tabs which have no space to show will be hidden automatically.