# Sherlock action bar navigation tab title not shown fully

Tags: android, tabs, actionbarsherlock

I have implemented sherlock action bar with 5 tabs that scrolls horizontally. The problem is some navigation tab title comes in two lines due to length. I have tried giving single line constraint in styles of actionbar tab. Even then the full title is not shown. for example 'Notification' is shown as 'Notificati...' in action bar . how to make the whole title visible in action bar. any style attributes are available, please provide suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Use Scrollable Tabs instead (the one similar to tabs in play store app)

http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html

Rule of thumb for this is that the tabs titles should be relevant.

Comment: I have implemented the application using action bar sherlock. is there any way to style action bar Sherlock for getting title in single line android. any suggestions.

Comment: I assume you're using fixed tabs. For fixed tabs, if you have 3, and maximum 4 tabs of which the contents are not so relevant, you should use fixed tabs.

If you have more than that, and tabs' content are relevant, you should use scrollable tabs.

If your elements are top-level elements (e.g something like home, history and setting pages), and number of elements is large, consider navigation drawer.

Those are recommendations for Android UI design. From what I understand of you app, you should use scrollable tabs. It's easy enough to replace fixed tabs with scrollable tabs.

Comment: Found something you might be interested in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10912602/swipeytabs-how-to-create-swipey-tabs-using-actionbarsherlock-library

Comment: i have implemented swipey tabs but if tab title of tabs is large it occupies two lines . I need the tab title to be in single line.if i give single line attribute in styles of actionbartabtext, title gets cropped.

Answer (score 0):

In order to have the titles of the bars on a single line, you can add the following style :

```html
 <style name="ActionBarTab" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabText">
        <item name="android:singleLine">true</item>
 </style>
```

However, this can lead to the cropping of the text and not the whole title will be visible, so you will need to configure the width of the tabs, too.

This shuold have been a comment, but I don't have enough reputation to make one.