# Change Tab / Fragment from Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabhost, android-fragmentactivity, android-tabs

I have a Main.class that extends from FragmentActivity and implements TabHost.OnTabChangeListener.
I have have 4 tabs ans this call 4 class that extends from Fragment.

For example if I am in the fragment of the tab1 and press a button to access the tab2, I do the following:

```
public class Tab01 extends Fragment {
...
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Main.class);
intent.putExtra("Screen","Tab02");
Tab01.this.startActivity(intent);
getActivity().finish();
...
}
```

And in Main.class :

```
public class Main extends FragmentActivity implements TabHost.OnTabChangeListener {
.....
private void initialiseTabHost(Bundle args) {
..
String nameTab = "";
String nameTabExtra = myIntent.getStringExtra("Screen");
if(nameTabExtra == null){
            mTabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
        }else{
            if (nameTabExtra.equals("Tab01")){
                nameTab = "Tab01";
                mTabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
            }else if (nameTabExtra.equals("Tab02")){
                nameTab = "Tab02";
                mTabHost.setCurrentTab(1);              
            }else if (nameTabExtra.equals("Tab03")){
                nameTab = "Tab03";
                mTabHost.setCurrentTab(2);
            }else if (nameTabExtra.equals("Tab04")){
                nameTab = "Tab04";
                mTabHost.setCurrentTab(3);
            } 
        }
this.onTabChanged(nameTab);
```

This works but is it the only way? Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Sound like what you are trying to do would fit Swipey Tab pattern perfectly.

http://www.pushing-pixels.org/2011/08/11/android-tips-and-tricks-swipey-tabs.html

[SwipeyTabs - how to create Swipey Tabs using ActionBarSherlock Library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10912602/swipeytabs-how-to-create-swipey-tabs-using-actionbarsherlock-library)

Comment: Thanks but no use to me.
I want is to change tab / fragment from a "Fragment" passing parameters and calling "FragmentActivity" with my current structure.